# Fetch distinct id's based on few criteria in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In Angular, I am trying to fetch distinct id's based on few condition. Below are the details

**JSON data**

```
 {
         "id":1,
         "fname":"Tes1",
         "lname":"Testname1",
         "personaldata":{
            "bloodgroup":A,
            "country":IN,
            "email":test@test.com
         }
 },
 {
         "id":12,
         "fname":"Tes2",
         "lname":"Testname2",
         "personaldata":{
            "bloodgroup":B,
            "country":US,
            "email":test@test.com
         }
 },
 {
         "id":13,
         "fname":"Tes3",
         "lname":"Testname3",
         "personaldata":{
            "bloodgroup":AB,
            "country":IN,
            "email":test@test.com
         }
 }
```

> If **"bloodgroup"** is **"A"** and **"county"** is **"IN"** fetch
> distinct **"id"**

**OUTPUT**

```
{"id":1},
{"id":13}
```

Comment: you mean {"id":13} ?

Comment: Based on your data, it should return only `{ "id": 1 }`. This should be easy which you can use `.filter()` to filter the matching element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :
To filter your data using condition :

```
 filter(d=> d.personaldata.bloodgroup=="A" && d.personaldata.country=='IN')
```

Remove Duplication :

```
 filter((n, i) => data.indexOf(n) === i)
```

Map data :

```
 map(d=>d.id);
```

Full Example :

```
const data =  [{
         "id":1,
         "fname":"Tes1",
         "lname":"Testname1",
         "personaldata":{
            "bloodgroup":"A",
            "country":"IN",
            "email":"test@test.com"
         }
 },
 {
         "id":12,
         "fname":"Tes2",
         "lname":"Testname2",
         "personaldata":{
            "bloodgroup":"B",
            "country":"US",
            "email":"test@test.com"
         }
 },
 {
         "id":13,
         "fname":"Tes3",
         "lname":"Testname3",
         "personaldata":{
            "bloodgroup":"AB",
            "country":"IN",
            "email":"test@test.com"
         }
 }];
 const dataFiltredAndDistinct = data
 .filter(d=> d.personaldata.bloodgroup=="A" && d.personaldata.country=='IN')
 .filter((n, i) => data.indexOf(n) === i)
 .map(d=>d.id);
 console.log(dataFiltredAndDistinct);
```